# calculate the sum of sales - sql

Tags: sql, sum

I would like to add all the 1's and 0's for column field2 and use the output of sum into new column

```
SELECT        
   field1, field2, field3, field4....., 
   SUM(CASE WHEN field2= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS field1s, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN field2= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS field0s
FROM 
   dbo.TableName
GROUP BY 
   field1, field2, field3, field4.....;
```

This method does not provide the output that i need. To illustrate what I need let me show you a example; I have columns `customerName`, `wentShopping`. For each customer I would like to calculate the total amount of time he/she went shopping and place the output into new column.

I have written the SQL query but it does not provide the sum of each customer?

This is the output I am getting:

```
customerName wentShopping wentShopping0 wentShopping1
   test          1           0             1
   .
   .
   test          1           0             1
```

but it should be:

```
customerName wentShopping wentShopping0 wentShopping1
   test          1           2             2
```

This is because total time test went shopping is twice and total time he didn't go shopping is also twice

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sums by customer, then you need to have the customer name in the group by. For example:

```
SELECT customerName
       , MAX(wentShopping) AS wentShopping -- did the customer go shopping at all?
       , SUM(CASE 
           WHEN wentshopping = 1 THEN 1   /* or other column for hours shopped */
           ELSE 0 
           END) AS wentShopping1,
       , SUM(CASE
           WHEN wentShopping = 0 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END) AS wentShopping0
       -- , MAX(age) AS age -- a line like this can pull in other data about the customer
FROM   dbo.tablename 
-- we JUST group by customerName here, since we want exactly 1 grouping per customer
-- to do our sums here
GROUP  BY customerName
```

Comment: but what i want all the information about that customer e.g. his age, DOB etc...? and i want both total numbers of 1's and 0's

Comment: @Dip: I've added an example of how to get age here. Since age will be the same for all rows in the group, we can just grab one of those values with MAX (or MIN)

Comment: this gets me the same output 1's and 0's for each customer, it does not provide me with the sum, it only provides the sum of one row. what if the same person went shopping twice. i have shown the output i am getting

Comment: @Dip The sum you wrote represents COUNT functionality, you can turn it into SUM by replacing the "1" after the "THEN" with the name of the column that represents a session total shopping time:
`SUM(CASE WHEN wentshopping = 1 THEN totalshoppingtime ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: i have tried you query and i have also tried this: 'SUM(CASE WHEN wentshopping = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wentshopping ' i am getting same data just one row gets added?

Comment: @Dip: I've edited my post to try and match the sample table and desired output you posted. If this doesn't work, please post some sample input data (e. g. from dbo.TableName)

Answer (score 0):

I think below will help you

```
SELECT  field1
       ,field3
       ,field4
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN field2 = 1 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS timeShoppedFor1
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN field2 = 0 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS timeShoppedFor0
FROM    dbo.TableName
GROUP BY field1
       ,field3
       ,field4
```

You can add all the filed in the group by clouse which you want.

**Query from comment:**

```
SELECT  customerName
       ,wentShopping
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN wentShopping0 = 1 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS wentShopping0
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN wentShopping1 = 1 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS wentShopping1
FROM    TableName
GROUP BY customerName
       ,wentShopping
```

Comment: is this query the same as my question, i am not getting the total it just provides me with 1's and 0's. i have shown the output i am getting

Comment: Select customerName,wentShopping,SUM(CASE WHEN wentShopping0 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as wentShopping0,
SUM(CASE WHEN wentShopping1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as wentShopping1
from table
group by  customerName,wentShopping

Comment: I think above query will help you for your required output